# Is there a way to aggregate countries into regions in R?

Tags: r, aggregate, region, country-codes

I have data that looks like this:

```
Date        Value     Country
1/1/2020      0        China
1/2/2020      2        China
1/1/2020      8        Mexico
1/2/2020      9        Mexico
1/1/2020      1        Japan
1/2/2020      2        Japan
```

But I am trying to find some way to aggregate the values by date and country and then relabel the new values at a regional level, so to look something like this:

```
Date        Value     Region
1/1/2020      2        Asia
1/2/2020      4        Asia
1/1/2020      8     Latin America
1/2/2020      9     Latin America
```

I've tried ifelse like this:

```
raw %>% 
  group_by(Region = if_else(Region %in% c("Southern Asia","Eastern Asia", "Southeast Asia", "Central Asia","Western Asia"), "Asia", 
                   if_else(Region %in% c("Northern Africa","Sub-Saharan Africa"), "Africa",
                   if_else(Region %in% c("Southern Europe","Eastern Europe","Western Europe"), "Europe",
                   if_else(Region %in% c("Latin America"), "Latin American and Caribbean", 
                            "North America")), 
           Date)) %>% 
  summarise(Value = sum(Value))
```

but it's not working and I'm sure I'm missing a step. If anyone could help me, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing this with nested `if_else`, if we have a key/val dataset it would be easier.  The 'world' dataset from 'poliscidata' have the columns 'country' and 'regionun' on which we can do a join and then do a group by `sum`

```
library(poliscidata)
library(dplyr)
data(world)
world %>% 
   select(Country = country, Region = regionun) %>% 
   right_join(raw) %>% 
   group_by(Date, Region) %>%
   summarise(Value = sum(Value), .groups = 'drop')
```

#### data

```
raw <- structure(list(Date = c("1/1/2020", "1/2/2020", "1/1/2020", "1/2/2020", 
"1/1/2020", "1/2/2020"), Value = c(0L, 2L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L), Country = c("China", 
"China", "Mexico", "Mexico", "Japan", "Japan")), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```